# Can i copy generated vtk dlls

Tags: java, vtk

I generated VTK dlls from sources (using C make and visual studio) in windows 7 (64 bits) to run with java code. Can I use this dlls  in other windows 64 bits systems ( windows 8, winddows 7,... )by coping them into this systems  and adding them to system path?

Comment: What stops you from just trying if it works?

Comment: I did that. My programme is runnig in some pcs and I get errors in others. I did not khown the source of this error it may be the .Net frame Work version, visual c++, or from vtk dlls,...